# Extracting MP4-Direct link from JWPlayer?

Tags: html, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am trying to extract a videolink from a streaming website.

So I use PHP and "file_get_contents" to open the videolink and then "explode" to find the link to the generated link

Its looks like `config5/videoid/generatedhash/` but you can access it also with `config5/videoid/`

So when I open this link I see this:

```
document.write('<div id="mediaspace2" style="width:880px;height:495px">');

jwplayer.key="key";
document.write('<div id="mediaspace" itemprop="video"></div>');
var scrwid=window.screen.width;
var def=false;
if(scrwid<1200) def=true;
   jwplayer("mediaspace").setup({
        sources: [{
                file: "http://linkto.mp4",
                label: "1080p HD",
        type: "mp4"
                }
                 ,{
                file: "http://linkto.mp4",
                label: "720p HD",
                type: "mp4",
                }        ,{
                file: "http://linkto.mp4",
                label: "360p",
        type: "mp4",
        "default": def
            }
```

and a lot more stuff

when i copy one link of my choice and open it in chrome everything is fine. but when i try to embed it with html5 video tags it opens a file named na.flv

ist like a security for the website

how can i decrypt it? :/

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: what do you mean with "where"?

Comment: i need to know why does it gives me an error when i try to embed it directly.. i mean it the refferrer or a cookie or what?

Comment: I need a link in order to see the error myself.